# Expressions in my template literal don't get updated

Tags: javascript, expression, variable-assignment, evaluation, template-literals

I define the variable `description` as a template literal with an expression in it. When I then use `description` later in `runScenario`, the expression returns what `money` started as, not what it currently is.

```
var money = 100;
var description = `You have ${money} money`;

function payday { 
    money += 50;
}

function runScenario {
    console.log(description);
}
```

No matter how many times `payday` is run, the output is always "You have 100 money".

I expected that the expression would be evaluated every time the variable is called, but I'm finding that the expression is only evaluated when defining the variable.

How do I fix this? What could I do instead?

Comment: because it is evaluated once, it does not keep updating. The `var description` line would need to be in the `runScenario` function.

Comment: You are correct in your finding. You can simply reset `description` in the `payday` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is evaluated instantly, and only once, in your code. You can use an arrow function to apply the template on demand:

```js
let money = 100;
const getDescription = () => `You have ${money} money`;
const payday = () => money += 50;
const runScenario = () => console.log(getDescription());

runScenario();
payday();
runScenario();
```

Comment: The problem is that `description` is actually an array of many strings and I might need to print any one of them, so I can't know exactly what I need to evaluate. Ideally my goal is to initialize that description array in a JSON file. 

Is there any way to initialize a variable with an expression that would get re-run? It doesn't feel like there is, but in that case I'm very confused how people manage to make random event generators for their games like I'm trying to do. 

I might need to ask a broader question about the structure of my game if there isn't an answer to this one

Comment: Supplementary question: is it possible to create functions from data in a JSON file? As long as I could somehow use a loop to make functions like `getDescription` I could use the method you suggested. I think I'm a little in over my head because that doesn't sound possible either, haha

Comment: @pyradim what you've described is very simple. The first step is to load the JSON into a variable (or just make the JSON part of the code instead of loading an external file), the second step is to pick an item from that variable at random. You should be able to easily search for answers on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Description variable value is assigned at line 2 hence it won't change although money variable is change

```
var money = 100;
var description = `You have ${money} money`;

function payday { 
    money += 50;
    description = `You have ${money} money`;
}

function runScenario {
    console.log(description);
}
```

Or create function that will return description

```
const getDescription = () => `You have ${money} money`;
```